# Text-To-Speech Restarting

Tags: android, android-service

I have `text-to-speech` services in my app. I also have a Check Box. When the text-to-speech completed.I want the text-to-speech to be restarted all the time when the checkBox is true.
Please anyone help me.

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: while (true){enter code here

           //////
            ////// i want here my text-to-speech to be restarted.
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Generate the “text to speech” first to an MP3 file and play the audio file . Normally the audio control has an “on end” event in each language.  Here you can put the check if you need play the audio again.It can also reduce the cost of using the TTS service. Pay once and play unlimited